# Rails4: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty in form_for on sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive the following error.

```
ArgumentError in Articles#index
Showing e:/xxx/app/views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb where line #1 raised: 
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

What I want to do is to display text_area on **sidebar** at all times for user to be able to enter comments.

`comments` doesn't have any relation.

Should I set `@comment` in `articles_controller` as well as `comments_controller`? Though I've tried some, they don't work.

\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
...
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
    　　<div class="row">
        <aside class="span3">
      　　<section>
        　　<%= render 'shared/comment_form' %>
      　　</section>
        </aside>
        <aside class="span9">
          <%= yield %>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
          <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

\app\views\shared_comment_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Enter your comment..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

\app\controllers\comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Sent your comment."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end

end
```

\app\models\comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :content, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

\app\controllers\articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
..
  def index
    @articles = Article.all(limit: 10)
  end
..
```

Please advise me on how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
```

in your `\app\views\shared_comment_form.html.erb` to

```
<%= form_for(Comment.new) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Why does this work? It isn't the same thing as creating the object in the controller and passing the variable to the view?

Comment: @dehq : Sure, but the OP wants to use this form on different routes and with different controllers. It doesn't make much sense to initialize `@comment` on every controller.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way the code is currently written in the example, you will need a `@comment` instance variable provided at the controller level anywhere you want to use that form to enter a comment. If you're going to use this form site-wide, it's best to provide a `@comment` instance variable in a `before_action` in your `ApplicationController` class, like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :create_comment

  def create_comment
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
end
```